# Adding entities sets dynamically in dbcontext the repository layer doesnt compile

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

My DbContext code is similar to this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
   public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

And I want to add dbsets in dbcontext dinamically, with a code similar to this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var baseAssemblyName = "Namespace.Web.Model";
    var assemblyType = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName.Equals(baseAssemblyName));

    //Culture is a class defined in the assembly where my Entity models reside
    var typesToRegister = assemblyType.GetTypes()
        .Where(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.Equals(baseAssemblyName))
        .Where(type => type.BaseType.IsGenericType && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));

    foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
    {
        dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
    }
}
```

But it is not executing, I put a breakpoint in the beggining of this method and at that point there are building errors in the repository layer that uses for example:

```
public ICustomer Get(int id)
{
    return db.Customers.Find(id);
}
```

What can i do for create dinamically the entities in dbcontext?

Thanks!

Comment: What build errors? And where exactly? Is the error you're getting saying something like `... does not contain a definition for '...'`?

Comment: This is the error that i get: Error CS1061 'IMyDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Customers' and no extension method 'Customers' accepting a first argument of type 'IMyDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) MyProject.Web.DataAccess

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should use Dbset like this.

```
public ICustomer Get(int id)
{
   return db.Set<Customer>().Find(id);
}
```